# Google App Engine - Can not find my logging messages

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I can not find the results of my logging calls.
To log messages I tried both:

```
System.out.println("some message");
```

and

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogger"); // Logger is java.util.logging.Logger 

// ... 

logger.info("some message");
```

I have deployed my app and after few tests I decided check out some 
log messages. But there were no messages. I changed minimum severity 
level to "Info" from default "Error", and only messages i've seen were 
service messages like this:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1678938/logs.png

I would also be grateful if someone show a little snippet with logging some data (if it's works) - I suspect my problem may be the one of that stupid problems when somewhat incorrectly located comma can be the cause of situation.

Comment: Did you click the + signs next to those log messages to expand them?  As displayed, it's impossible to tell if things you logged are actually in the log.

Comment: yes, i clicked +'es - there're was nothing similar with the info, i logged in my app. Only "dummy" strings describing some requests to the app

Comment: Are you looking at the logs for the correct version of your app?  It is possible that you deployed to version X but are looking at the logs for version Y.

Comment: before posting my problem here i had only one version. Now i'm trying out different versions, changing logging techiques, but with no results yet

Comment: I also have this problem. I am unable to see my logging messages. Even exceptions. Stuck with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem has shrunk into more concrete form - App Engine "eats" info-messages, but shows others, such as error and warning messages.

After this call I have eventually seen my info messages:

```
log.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

But it is still not clearly - why info-messages weren't being shown. Google's [manual](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html) states:

> Everything the servlet writes to the
>   standard output stream (System.out)
>   and standard error stream (System.err)
>   is captured by App Engine and recorded
>   in the application logs. Lines written
>   to the standard output stream are
>   logged at the "INFO" level, and lines
>   written to the standard error stream
>   are logged at the "WARNING" level.

Comment: Except this decision I found one more way - try to edit file WEB-INF/logging.properties. It has only one string - you should chahge WARNING level to INFO (or somewhat else)

Answer (score 27):

Could it be that your `logging.properties` is setting the default value to `WARNING`?

Ours has this in our `war/WEB-INF/logging.properties` file:

```
# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = WARNING

# Default level for subpackages of 'server' will be INFO
com.company.whatever.server.level=INFO
```

Answer (score 8):

Had exactly the same problem and after changing the value in logging.properties from

.level = WARNING

to

.level = INFO

The problem was definitively fixed. Google needs to update their documentation and/or change the value of the supplied default so that "INFO" log messages don't get swallowed.

Comment: Agree with the Google doc sentiment.  And, to elaborate, the different, dependent pieces need to be documented together with all the sample code, configuration, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used to set `LEVEL` to `SEVERE` for testing

```
 logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "test message");
```

It does not need changing any value in logging.properties